# Python Regex Cycle for Extracting info

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a function to make an apply function that the end is to find the numbers followed by 3 characters in this case `alc`. The expected result should be = 54

```
import pandas as pd 
import regex as re 

numeros=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

i="sdASK23LJFASDFKJGHASDLKJF123HALSDKJFHASDF54 alcobas"
     
df=df.head(3)

def re_alcoba(i):
    i=i.replace(" ", "")
    patron_acoba=re.compile(r"alc")
    matches=patron_acoba.finditer(i)
    contador=1
    numero_alcobas=[]
    for match in matches:
        index=match.start()
    while contador < 3: 
        numero=i[index-contador]
        contador+=1
        if numero in numeros: 
            numero_alcobas.insert(0,numero)
    respuesta="".join(numero_alcobas)
    return respuesta
            
            
respuesta=re_alcoba(i)
```

[My Cicle wont work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNEkn.jpg)

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: why not `(\d+)alc` or `([0123456789]+)alc`

Comment: maybe you should change indentations and run `while`-loop inside `for`-loop

Comment: The thing is they could be numbers before the numbers corresponding to ALC so for example 4asd5alc

Comment: maybe show better example and expected result.

Comment: I will thanks, fist time posting on stack. All feedback is usefull

Comment: what with example `4asd5alc`? What result do you expect? If `45` then you should also show it in question because it is unusuall expectation. And if you expct only `5` then `(\d+)alc` should resolve it.

Comment: the expected result in this case should be 5

Comment: then `re.findall("(\d+)alc", "4asd5alc")` should gives `5` and you don't need all your function

Comment: Deeply appreciate your help i will test it and comment again if something new happen

Answer (score 1):

If you want numbers directly before `alc` then you don't need all this code but simply `(\d+)alc`

```
import regex as re 

i = "sdASKLJFASDFKJGHASDLKJFHALSDKJFHASDF54alcobas"
i = i.replace(" ", "")
results = re.findall("(\d+)alc", i)
print(results) # ['54']

i = "4asd5alc"
i = i.replace(" ", "")
results = re.findall("(\d+)alc", i)
print(results) # ['5']
```

Answer (score 0):

As there are spaces in your example string, you can either match optional spaces except newlines after the digits:

```
(\d+)[^\S\n]*alc
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zcigev/1)

```
import re

pattern = r"(\d+)[^\S\n]*alc"

s = ("sdASK23LJFASDFKJGHASDLKJF123HALSDKJFHASDF54 alcobas\n"
    "4asd5alc")
    
print(re.findall(pattern, s))
```

Output

```
['54', '5']
```